# How to display some html text from a database in a VIew within a TD cell, but only first 300 chars.....?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Not sure if this is possible, but I have some HTML in a DB column which I want to display in a Table TD cell in a Razor View. However the issue is that I only want the first 300 chars followed by "..."

ie:

```
<h2>My Test</h2> 

<p>My Test description is very long</p>
```

So if I return the first 25 chars for the purpose of this question plus "...", I would get:

```
<h2>My Test</h2> 

<p>My Tes ...
```

Which would then upset the containing page, due to the invalid HTML

ie

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>

<h2>My Test</h2> 

<p>My Tes ...

   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way round this?

At the moment I am using:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.myTestHtml)
```

to display the test HTML.

Perhaps I can only strip out the text from the HTMl and then .substring this.

Thanks appreciated.

Comment: does @Html.Raw(Model.myTextHtml.Substring(0,300)) work?

Comment: Hi Matt, I have tried this, and this is how I found the problem, since it just chops the HTML in half, or first 300 chars to be exact!

Comment: I thought that was what you were looking for.  did you want them to be able to click the ... to see the rest?

Comment: Hi Matt, I ended up going with the CKEditor Control as a lateral solution. Works a charm.

Comment: we use ckeditor also.  great tool

Comment: Just found that it does not play well with IOS and Android, at all... May have to swap out CKEditor :( Have anothe SO question on this :) Possibly JQuery now. Just found "redactor" which looks very good, but there are loads of them !!??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the html is not dynamic and it always follows same pattern, you may:

Parse the html to xml content
use LINQ2XML and find the node you want in there
edit that text and replace the additional parts with (...)
parse back to html
render it

LINQ2XML is very reliable. I am not sure if you can find dependencies which does same work as it with same level of accuracy and performance. but if you do find it, then you would not need to parsing in the process(to xml and from xml)

Comment: Sadly the HTML does not show the same pattern, just that it is HTML. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I would be interested to know if you find a solution

Comment: Hi Shayan, yes I did find a solution. Basically some lateral thinking helped me. I used the CKEditor control for rich text editing, and it is great at rendering HTML in a contained way. So I now use a read only version of the control which provides realistic HTML rendering and with a vertical scroll bar.It is better than what I could ever get by incorporating the HTML fragment into the parent HTML page.

Comment: Until you want to use a mobile device :( Next SO question.... So may be using another control/plugin.